# How to add selective datasets for legends

Tags: plot, legend, matlab-figure, legend-properties

I have a plot in which 15 datasets are plotted along with their trendlines(lslines). If i use the command legend, it displays all the datasets and lslines, totally 30 legends. But i want to ignre legends of lslines. How is it possible?

Comment: Please provide a minimum code which shows your problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith , it runs in a lopp, plots the graph, draws "lsline" and holds on for next iterations. So i need only legends for the plots not for lslines...

Answer (score 1):

Store the handles from each plotted data set and use those to create the legend:

```
figure
hold on
h1 = plot(rand(1,10),'b');
h2 = plot(rand(1,10),'r');
h3 = plot(rand(1,10),'g');

legend([h1,h3],'data 1','data 3') %displays a legend for the first and third plot but not the second plot
```